# Polymer linter JSdoc directive for extending a legacy element

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I've extended an element with

```
const PaperSliderClass = customElements.get('paper-slider');
class MyPaperSlider extends PaperSliderClass {
...
```

But how do I tell the polymer linter/build about it?
I tried to add the following right before my class declaration, but it didn't work.

```
/**
* @polymer
* @customElement
* @extends {PaperSliderClass}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

apparently I could just do:

```
@appliesMixin paper-slider
```